# Passing multiple arguments to script linux

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I've got the following code, which is supposed to take filenames as arguments, and send them to my email address, which is derived from a username:

```
#Email Script from linux
#Define username e.g. pp_roman
u="$USER"

#Remove the pp_ and store to variable e.g. roman

u2=${u#"pp_"}

#Define Email portion

em="@workemail.com"

#Combine the username e.g. roman@workemail.com

u3=$u2$em

#Arguments for script

for FILE1 in "$@"
do
    filename="-a $FILE1"
done

##This returns the full string with $filename variables for arguments, and email from $u3

mailx $filename -s "Subject" $u3 < /dev/null
```

However when passing multiple arguments, only the last mentioned filename is sent as an attachment. How do I pass multiple arguments into the $filename variable all appended by "-a"?

Comment: What shell are you actually using? `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, `dash`? Or does this need to conform to the POSIX specification for portability?

Comment: bash. Currently looking at adding functionality to refuse transfer of files over say 5 meg? don't know how resource intensive mailx is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `bash`, the right thing to use is an array.

```
attachments=()
for f in "$@"
do
    attachments+=(-a "$f")
done

mailx "${attachments[@]}" -s "Subject" "$u3" < /dev/null
```

Comment: Would this work for filenames with whitespaces? Previous comment suggested single quotes for '$f', or is this the type input for arrays?

Comment: Quoted array expansion using `[@]` is specifically designed to solve the problem of storing a sequence of values containing whitespace.